# Is it possible to use Jest with multiple presets at the same time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, react-native, jestjs

Is it possible to use Jest with multiple presets, say jsdom and react-native?

I'd like to test a React component that can work both on Web and in a React Native environment. The problem is that the component may use either React Native libraries or some document's methods.

When I run some tests, jest replies:

> Cannot find module 'NetInfo' from 'react-native-implementation.js'

When I try to add

```
"jest": {
  "preset": "react-native"
}
```

to package.json, I get:

> ReferenceError: window is not defined

Answer (score 41):

Presets are just plain Javascript objects, so in many circumstances you may simply merge them. For example, that's how I'm enabling `ts-jest` and `jest-puppeteer` simultaneously:

```
const merge = require('merge')
const ts_preset = require('ts-jest/jest-preset')
const puppeteer_preset = require('jest-puppeteer/jest-preset')

module.exports = merge.recursive(ts_preset, puppeteer_preset, {
    globals: {
        test_url: `http://${process.env.HOST || '127.0.0.1'}:${process.env.PORT || 3000}`,
    },
})
```

If there are certain options that can't be 'merged' like that, just handle these cases manually.

Comment: [merge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/merge)
Merge multiple objects into one, optionally creating a new cloned object. Similar to the jQuery.extend but more flexible. Works in Node.js and the browser.

Comment: How is this file then referenced in jest.config?

Answer (score 31):

Along these same lines, you can do this with the spread operator:

```js
const tsPreset = require('ts-jest/jest-preset')
const puppeteerPreset = require('jest-puppeteer/jest-preset')

module.exports = {
  ...tsPreset,
  ...puppeteerPreset,
  globals: {
    test_url: `http://${process.env.HOST||'127.0.0.1'}:${process.env.PORT||3000}`,
  }, 
}
```

Comment: It is odd that @Ilya's example uses recursive merge, and this equivalent doesn't.  I wonder which is correct?

Comment: Recursive merge is probably safer, especially if the config contains nested options, though at the time the simple spread merge was sufficient

Answer (score 1):

For people that are looking for one preset plus typeScript

```
const { defaults: tsjPreset } = require('ts-jest/presets')

module.exports = merge.recursive(ts_preset, puppeteer_preset, {
    preset: 'Your_Preset',
    transform: tsjPreset.transform,
    },
})
```