# How to use multiple Jest presets with only one Jest configuration file/setup?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, amazon-dynamodb, jestjs

A project I'm working on is already configured with Jest and testing works as it should. This is how the current `jest.config.js` file looks like;

```
const ignores = [...];
const coverageIgnores = [...];

module.exports = {
  roots: ['<rootDir>/src'],
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      tsConfig: 'tsconfig.json',
    },
  },
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'json', 'ts'],
  testPathIgnorePatterns: [...ignores],
  coveragePathIgnorePatterns: [...ignores, ...coverageIgnores],
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  coverageThreshold: {
    global: {
      branches: 86,
      functions: 75,
      lines: 86,
      statements: 86,
    },
  },
  preset: 'ts-jest',
};
```

The configuration currently uses the `ts-jest` preset. The project also involves a DynamoDB instance that should be tested and that's where multiple presets come into play. The current preset, `ts-jest`, should be used in combination with the `@shelf/jest-dynamodb`-preset (https://jestjs.io/docs/en/dynamodb). The problem is that the preset property in the config is of type String and doesn't support an array or an object.

I've read some similar questions like this one; [Is it possible to use Jest with multiple presets at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51002460/is-it-possible-to-use-jest-with-multiple-presets-at-the-same-time), but questions like these don't seem to have a definitive working solution on how to solve this problem.

Others suggest a solution in which a separate Jest config is created for every preset, but this is something I don't want and that probably will cause more problems in the future.

**It would be ideal to have this single config file modified to allow multiple (here 2) presets, but how can this be achieved?**

Comment: Did you find any solution so far?

Comment: No I don't, it doesn't seem to be documented how to do this. I'm also not dealing with this issue anymore since I'm not working on that project anymore.

Answer (score 6):

You can't actually use two presets but since the preset for shelf/jest-dynamodb is just setting other options in the jest setup, you can call them yourself. I was able to do this by just adding to my "jest" section of package.json:

```
"globalSetup": "./node_modules/@shelf/jest-dynamodb/setup.js",
"globalTeardown": "./node_modules/@shelf/jest-dynamodb/teardown.js",
```

This makes the same calls that the preset was doing, meaning you can leave the preset to ts-jest

Comment: Could you elaborate this more? There's literary 0 information on the Internet about why you can't have more than one preset. How would you put ts-jest with other presents together?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51002460/is-it-possible-to-use-jest-with-multiple-presets-at-the-same-time/52622141 this can be useful

Answer (score 1):

This is specific to the marriage of `ts-jest` and `jest-dynamodb`, but what worked for me was to change the jest config like this:

```json
"jest": {
    "preset": "@shelf/jest-dynamodb",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.tsx?$": [
        "ts-jest",
        {}
      ]
    },
    // ...
  }
```